# how to get category details while displaying subcategories?

Tags: php, mysql

I have category and subcategory tables.

My subcategory table contains `cat_id` column.

Now I want to displaying all sub categories with their category id and category name in one html table.

How can I achieve it in a single query?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve that with an `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT sc.*, c.* FROM subcategory sc INNER JOIN category c ON sc.category_id = c.id
```

Comment: you can achieve that with a `select`, what kind of lmgtfy answer is that?

Comment: a short one, to be the first who answers - I edited it with the code now :D

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT subcat.name, subcat.cat_id, cat.name FROM subcat
INNER JOIN cat ON (subcat.cat_id = cat.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to lookup the SQL command JOIN: [Read up on SQL joins here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please check out [this article](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/). This is what you want and what you need - even if it looks complicated at first glance.

Second, as an solution to your current question. You will need to join the data from the tables. (Read [JOIN SYNTAX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)). Other answers already have the exact query.

Comment: for just cats and subcats that article is way way overkill. This stuff is trivial your link is advanced.